# Zend session handling advices for newbie :)

Tags: zend-framework, session

I wanted to ask about the session handling in Zend Framework. I am using Zend_Session_Namespace for my session handling. My question is how should I implement this in an efficient way? At this moment I have a session check in every one of my controller's actions.

How should I handle the session handling for example in the layout file, because the way I'm doing it now (checking in every action using sessionExists() and checking if userId is set) seems very inefficient and repetitive.

thanx for all the support! :)

P.S. If it's any help, here's a function I use for session checking in my controller:

```
 private function checkSession()
        {
            $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace("userSession");
            if(Zend_Session::sessionExists() && $session->__isset("userId"))
            {
            return true;    
            }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should probably check out Zend_Acl and front controller plugins. By their powers combined, that is your solution ;)

Comment: You might also want to take a look at Zend_Auth to store the userid. http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.auth.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link Joellord posted should help. If you need something to run on every request you should consider using a controller plugin - the [Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) is a good place to start out.

If you implement an auth system, this code will tell you whether or not a user is logged in:

> $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
>   if($auth->hasIdentity()) { //do something...

It can also be extended to provide you with a user object, their role / permissions, etc etc.

[This article](http://mwop.net/blog/165-Login-and-Authentication-with-Zend-Framework.html) by Matthew Weier O'Phinney is a fantastic resource to learn about basic authentication using Zend_Auth.